# Cmidrule on Table not working

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I've been trying to get a midrule line under Passing, but can't seem to get it to work. I've gotten it in the two other spots, but cannot figure out why it won't let me on this one. [image]

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Sieve Size}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Retaining} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Passing}  \\
\cmidrule(r){1-3}\cmidrule(r){4-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{US} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{in.} &  \multicolumn{1}{c} 
{mm.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cum. \%} &\multicolumn{1}{c} 
{\%}\\\midrule
$\frac{3}{8}$ & 0.5 & 12.5 & 4.2 & 4.2 & 95.8  \\ 
\#4 & 0.1870 & 4.75 & 23.7 & 27.9 & 72.1\\ 
\#8 & 0.0937 & 2.36 & 20.0 & 47.9 & 52.1 \\ 
\#16 & 0.0460 & 1.18 & 28.1 & 76.0 & 24.0\\
\#30 & 0.0240 & 0.60 & 7.1 & 83.1 & 16.9 \\
\#50 & 0.0120 & 0.30 & 8.4 & 91.5 & 8.5\\
\#100 & 0.0060 & 0.15 & 6.8 & 98.3 & 1.7 \\
Pan & -- & -- & 1.7 & 100 & 0 \\\midrule
Sum & & &100 & 528.9 & 271.0\\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You only have `cmidrule` from 1-5. Need under 6, too.

Comment: I was trying and that would just cause an error to show up.

Comment: Did you try `\cmidrule(l){6-6}`?

Comment: Welcome! Please don't post fragments of code, but complete minimal examples. Which error? What code can we use to reproduce it?

Comment: That worked, I was way overthinking that! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `\cmidrule{6-6}`

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Sieve Size}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Retaining} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Passing}  \\
\cmidrule(r){1-3}\cmidrule(r){4-5}\cmidrule{6-6}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{US} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{in.} &  \multicolumn{1}{c} 
{mm.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cum. \%} &\multicolumn{1}{c} 
{\%}\\\midrule
$\frac{3}{8}$ & 0.5 & 12.5 & 4.2 & 4.2 & 95.8  \\ 
\#4 & 0.1870 & 4.75 & 23.7 & 27.9 & 72.1\\ 
\#8 & 0.0937 & 2.36 & 20.0 & 47.9 & 52.1 \\ 
\#16 & 0.0460 & 1.18 & 28.1 & 76.0 & 24.0\\
\#30 & 0.0240 & 0.60 & 7.1 & 83.1 & 16.9 \\
\#50 & 0.0120 & 0.30 & 8.4 & 91.5 & 8.5\\
\#100 & 0.0060 & 0.15 & 6.8 & 98.3 & 1.7 \\
Pan & -- & -- & 1.7 & 100 & 0 \\\midrule
Sum & & &100 & 528.9 & 271.0\\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]